# What is posrelat() in Lua's source code?

Tags: lua

I was reading Lua's source code today, and while reading lstrlib.c, I found an interesting function called `static ptrdiff_t posrelat (ptrdiff_t pos, size_t len)`. A comment in the source code calls it "relative string position". What does it mean? Googling it seems to get me limited information. Could anyone explain its function and what `ptrdiff_t` is, and if possible, usage and application in Lua?

See https://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lstrlib.c.html

Comment: The body of that function is only 2 lines long. What specifically is confusing?

Comment: But what it does is spelled out both in the comment (which you only quoted part of) *and* in the source code. So what is it that you are not sure on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Lua docs](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.html), one may index into a string from the end using negative indices.  This function appears to be normalising potentially-negative indices to positive-only.